# How to increase the user' error times? unknown whether the original value is null

Tags: ms-access

Before operate Access database,in the SQL express,I can just use this statement and it works very well:

```
UPDATE Person
SET FErrorTimes = IsNull(FErrorTimes, 0) + 1
WHERE (FUserName = @name)
```

by now, it reports as error syntax

can someone help me please,and thanks very much.

Answer (score 1):

Access' `IsNull` is different than SQL Server's `IsNull`.  In Access, `IsNull` accepts only one argument, and returns True or False to indicate whether that argument evaluates as Null.

Use one of these instead.

```sql
UPDATE Person
SET FErrorTimes = Nz(FErrorTimes, 0) + 1
WHERE FUserName = @name

UPDATE Person
SET FErrorTimes = IIf(FErrorTimes Is Null, 0, FErrorTimes) + 1
WHERE FUserName = @name
```

Note `Nz()` is only available for a query run within an Access session.  If you're running a query from external code which connects to the Access db, use the second example.